# Locating Location Services

Tags: macos, preferences

In System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General, Location Services lists a variety of items that you can opt to give permission to accessing your location. I have listed in this pane an application which I deleted and which I am unable to find any other trace of on my computer. EasyFind usually works for me to find any hidden file, but it's not happening this time. I want to remove this item from the list of things I can grant location access to since it's not even installed anymore. How do I do this? Where is this item hiding?

Rebooting does nothing to change the situation.

The computer is a MacBook Air 2014 running the latest build of Yosemite. The application is called FaceBar and is a menubar app that runs a small version of FaceBook and I found a different app that does the same thing but in a way I like better so I deleted FaceBar and what I thought were all of its associated files with AppCleaner. As I mentioned, even while searching hidden files nothing with the name FaceBar appears but there it sits in Location Services.

Comment: Please give more detail about your computer... model and OS version.  What application?  How did you delete it?  Was it installed with an installer?...?

Comment: Also, rebooting the OS is a good thing to give the location daemon and system services a clean start without that App requesting location data.